# android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter not exsisting after upgrade Android Support Repository v 47.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an error after upgrading Android Support Repository to version 47.0.0 in Android Studio 2.3.3

android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter is not exsisting

Error: package android.support.v13.app does not exist

Comment: post your build.gradle